# How to display node number in content items that only show up to administrators on ALL content items?

Tags: nodes

Evertime I need to node number I need to go to content items and hover over it, memorize and use it after...

Is there a way to have the node number displayed on the content item, but only to administrator.

Is there a module for this? Or would I have to create a custom field with a token and add it to every display...?

Comment: I know the answer to your question, but...Why do you need to node number? I rarely use it...

Comment: I need it to create links on menu items, to assign blocks to specific nodes, to create links to content items in articles ect...many reasons!

Comment: Hey @NoSssweat as per your "I know the answer ...": I'd be interested in knowing about that too. Can you extend your answer to also explain that? FYI: the "What links here" block (view) seems to only work correctly (at least in my case) if internal links are created with "node/nid", and not if you use path aliases to create such links. Which is why I always avoid using path aliases to create internal links.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens the actual question is `Is there a way to have the node number displayed on the content item, but only to administrator` which can be accomplished in various ways: using views, or creating a block and a template file or creating a module and using hook_block() (over kill IMO) and giving access of role of administrator. `FYI: the "What links here" block (view) seems to only work correctly (at least in my case) if internal links are created with "node/nid"` I can provide a more detailed answer, but I am not sure if you're asking the same thing "How to print node id in a block?"

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I am a bit confused, when you say `"What links here" block (view)` is it the nodes that are linking to the current node? or is it just a list of nodes that link to their respective node?

Comment: @NoSssweat: yes the nodes that are linking to the current node, the view you can see within admin at "/admin/structure/views/view/backlinks".

Comment: At the content if you just hover your mouse over the "Edit" tab (or Edit link in the content list) your browser should display the url with the node #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need it to create links on menu items, to assign blocks to specific
> nodes, to create links to content items in articles ect...many
> reasons!

You're going the wrong way about this. Having your urls named `node/1`, `node/2` etc.. looks ugly and it's bad for SEO.

What you need to do is give your Content Types an url alias. You don't want your **How To Use Drupal** article url to be `node/1`. You want it to be `/articles/how-to-use-drupal`

You should use the **[Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto)** module. This module allows you to automatically create an url alias using tokens.

Then when you assign a block, you can use `articles/*` this will make the block show up on all articles urls.

**[Pathauto Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJUYsJA737o)**

> I knew about path auto, I just thought it was better practice to use
> node items for links and so on, in case I change the page name later,
> node number never changes...

You can use the **[redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect)** module which will auto redirect the old path to the new path if you change the path name. Thus, you don't have to worry about updating links.

To make life easier, I would also recommend

#### [CKEditor Link - A plugin to easily create links to Drupal internal paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link)

[image]

Comment: I knew about path auto, I just thought it was better practice to use node items for links and so on, in case I change the page name later, node number never changes...

Comment: @BrunoVincent you can use the [redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module which will auto redirect the old path to the new path if you change the path name. Thus, you don't have to worry about updating links.

Comment: @BrunoVincent updated answer.

Comment: There's some good information here, but it doesn't really answer the question. The **are** situations in which it's useful to know the node number, regardless of whether Path aliases, Pathauto module, etc, are in use or not. SEO is not imporant for all sites, and is not even relevant to some sites (consider intranet sites).

Comment: There are some situations where using the nid (node id number) is far superior to using the path alias to reference a node, simply because the nid never changes. Bruno said, "I need it to create links on menu items, to assign blocks to specific nodes, to create links to content items in articles ect...many reasons!" - these are some examples.

Comment: @netgenius.co.uk if you do SEO, there is no such situation.

Comment: @Sssweat I'm talking about using the nid as an *internal* reference, not an *external* URL path.

Comment: Solution is to hover on edit in back end, not perfect but it works

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in, and without resorting to using PHP in blocks (dangerous) or installing modules, here's the simplest method I can think of...

Paste the following code into your *settings.php* file, and clear Drupal's caches. This will display a message showing the node number on node view pages. It will only trigger for users who have *Administer content* permission.

```
// For content admins, display node number in a message.
function system_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if (user_access('administer nodes') && $view_mode == 'full') {
    drupal_set_message("Node number: $node->nid", 'warning');
  }
}
```

Edit: The above is for Drupal 7. For Drupal 8, define the function as `function system_node_view($node, $display, $view_mode)`. I haven't tested that but I think it should work.